# Computing sum in Theano using arange

Tags: python, numpy, range, theano

I need to compute a finite sum of terms running from 0 to 100*T with step T in Theano and the j-th term of the sum depend on j*T, being j an integer. Here T is a Theano scalar. What I tried to do is to use the function `theano.tensor.arange` in a numpy fashion

`for j in theano.tensor.arange(T,T*100,T):`

and then using the looping variable `j` inside the loop in order to compute the terms of the sum.
However, I got the error

`ValueError: length not known: ARange{dtype='float64'}`

and I don't know how to fix this issue.

I'm new to Theano, so it is possible that I'm missing something quite basic. Thank you for your help.